# Problem with passing context in Bluebird Promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I faced with situation where I need to pass some values to Promise handler. Below is example of situation

```
function promiseFunct(x){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       if(x>0) resolve(x);
       else if(x==0) resolve(1);
       else resolve(0);
  });
}

promiseFunct(-100).then(function(response){
  var someObj = { len: 124 };
  return promiseFunct(response).bind(someObj);
}).then(function(response){
    if(this.len) console.log(this.len); //not getting access here, this is Window
});
```

I'm trying to bind someObj and then get access to it in handler, but no success. Is there some elegant solution to pass some object to promise handler, except passing to Promise and then resolving inside Promise?

Comment: bind `someObj` to `function(response){ if(this.len) console.log(this.len);}`

Comment: @ChrisLi, someObj is not defined in this scope

Comment: Where does `someObj` come from? Why not just define it in the second callback?

Comment: @Bergi, if I could do it I would do. Let's assume that someObj is result of some hard calculations.

Comment: @VladislavVazhenin And why do those hard calculations need to be placed in exactly that scope? Please provide an example that makes the dependencies clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found simple solution, but there is no guarantee, that it's most elegant.

```
promiseFunct(-100).bind({}).then(function(response){
  this.len = 124 ;
  return promiseFunct(response);
}).then(function(response){
    if(this.len) console.log(this.len); // showing 124
});
```

With `bind({})` setting own Promise chain context which will not cross with `Window`, for example. If I had `len` value outside I could use `bind({len: len})`
Then I can use `this.propertyName` to get or set desired property for using in next handlers.

Answer (score 0):

First a look at what's going wrong:

```
promiseFunct(-100).then(function(response){
  var someObj = { len: 124 };
  return promiseFunct(response).bind(someObj);
})
```

returns a bound promise from the `then` fulfillment handler.

Promise code waits until the bound promise is settled before passing its state (fulfilled or rejected) and value ( data or rejection reason) down the promise chain. To do this it *internally*  calls `then` on the bound promise to obtain its outcome, and it's the internal handlers used which get called with the bound `this` value - which they simply ignore.

Although [Bluebird documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.bind.html) states

> ...  Additionally promises derived from a bound promise will also be bound promises with the same thisArg ...

that doesn't apply to this case: all promises in a chain of promises are created synchronously when the chain is defined, before any asynchronous processing of the chain begins.

Since promise chains only pass a single value between handlers, the simplest approach may be to pass a namespace object with any number of other values as required. Since subsequent handlers already needed to know where to look for additional data it shouldn't be too big a change:

```js
function promiseFunct(x){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       if(x>0) resolve(x);
       else if(x==0) resolve(1);
       else resolve(0);
  });
}
promiseFunct(-100).then(function(response){
console.log( "response " + response);
  var someObj = { len: 124 };
  var ns = {response, rest: someObj};
  return ns;
}).then(function({response, rest}){
    if(rest.len) console.log(rest.len);
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I still need call some function which will return Promise inside handler. In your example you are not calling promise function inside.

Comment: I just used second call of promiseFunct as example, it could be any function, which will return Promise. But anyway promiseFunct will resolve 0 first, and then 1, it returns Promise, I didn't see any need to write second Promise function

Comment: Good, my deleted comment wasn't needed! I see the solution you've adopted calls `then` on a promise which has been explicitly bound when declaring the promise chain - which I think is what the documentation means by "derived promise". Well done.